What are some general guidelines or tips to reading a mathematics textbook?
I am an undergraduate who started down the math educator path but found pure math to be very intriguing. As I enrolled in higher math courses, I found reading the textbook to be ever more important. My professor always says "You must actively read the textbooks, you cannot just spend 2 minutes per page." Does anyone else have any general tips for getting the most knowledge out of a math textbook?

Make sure you understand all the proofs

And do most problems!!

“Don't just read it; fight it! Ask your own questions, look for your own examples, discover your own proofs. Is the hypothesis necessary? Is the converse true? What happens in the classical special case? What about the degenerate cases? Where does the proof use the hypothesis?” — Paul Halmos

Always do all the proofs. At the very least, try to understand them.

It's a skill in itself and, like any other skill, becomes easier with practice. You should attend your professor's office hour to get some specific guidelines for your current textbook.

Pace other commenters, it's also really useful to learn how to skim: skip the proofs and just read the definitions and the statements of the lemmas, propositions and theorems, particularly definitions.  Try to see how these statements form a coherent narrative. Then when you go back over the details of the proofs, you will have a better idea of where you are going and why. (This does not go against your professor's advice: it can take a lot longer than 2 minutes to take in the statement of a hard definition or theorem.)

I generally write along, either on a small white board or paper. It makes sure I'm actually paying attention to what's occurring. I do this with papers/articles as well.
I usually have a second text that I'll reference if I cannot make sense of a part/passage.
I'll write details I think would be helpful to specify in the margins. This also helps when you need to pass through looking for why a specific thing works, since you've already clarified the explanation. This was an idea I adapted from the suggestion that this is a good way to take notes in graduate courses.
Of course doing as many problems as possible is important. If there aren't enough problems, a second text can be helpful there too. I wouldn't worry about doing all the problems, but I would be trying to do most. If there's $1$ I miss, oh well. If there's $7$ I can't do, that's too many.
While not usually possible, having somebody else who wants to work through the book as well is really helpful. Then you can discuss it, and double check understanding with each other. You can also read through sections as if you were preparing to teach the other person.
Last thing I'll mention is consistency. If you read a section one day, and don't touch the book for two weeks, you're probably not going to understand the next section.
